# How to iterate through all the classes defined in ExtJS application

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In a single-page ExtJS 6 application I need to scan through all classes ever declared with `Ext.define` method and find those implementing specific mixin. For simplicity let's assume that all classes I am interested in are already loaded, and on-demand loading mechanisms are out of the game.

There seems to be no other way to iterate than via private `Ext.ClassManager.classes` property. Is there a cleaner alternative?

Anyway, the above gives the list of class names. How to figure out whether corresponding classes implement specific mixin?

Comment: For specific you want to iterate over views/controller classes ?

Comment: No, those are general-purpose classes derived from Ext.Base in most of the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getClassesByMixin(mixin){
    var classes=[];
    Ext.iterate(Ext.ClassManager.classes,function(className,c){
        if(c.prototype &&c.prototype.mixins &&  c.prototype.mixins[mixin]){
            classes.push(className);
        }
    });
    return classes;
}
```

[Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1rh7)

Comment: Thanks, Theo. I've come up with almost the same solution myself. Just wondering why Sencha provides no clean reflection API